# Why does this table-cell method change the div height?

Tags: html, css

In this code snippet, the height of the black div is equal to the height of the image plus the height of the lorem ipsum paragraph

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG101V74417J

How do I fix it so that the black div ends at the bottom of whichever div is tallest? (e.g. right below the image)

Comment: You can start by leveraging `vertical-align:top` on both table cells, and removing `top:-280px` on the cell with the text.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things wrong with your code: You need to end the first `div` and also you open a p tag but close with a h3 tag.

Remove `top: -280px` and use `vertical-align: top` instead.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcbaswyv/